# Why do a stronger acid lose a proton easily when the electromagnetic force in a polar compound should keep it together?

Tags: acid-base

In acid-base theory I've just learned that the stronger the electronegativity, the stronger the acid will be at least it will have an impact on the strength of the acid.

If that so, then the acid should NOT lose a proton due to the electronegativity difference which makes the compound (acid) polar. I mean, shouldn't the electromangentic attraction between the positive side and the negative side ends of the compound have a greater force to keep it together rather than separate it into a conjugate base and a proton?
It does not make sense.

Comment: Acids not so much lose protons as *donate* them - it's the base that makes them act as acids.

Comment: I would suggest to please pay attention to correct spelling ('electromagnetic', 'compound', 'separate'), as well as capitalisation, when writing your question. Also, there's no reason to use a bullet point. You can [edit] your question to fix these.

Answer (score 3):

Chemical bonds aren't just electrostatic attractions between some cation $\ce{H+}$ and anion $\ce{X-}$. Well, *purely ionic bonds* are; but if you don't have a purely ionic bond, then there's some **covalent** part that also matters, which is the part that you're neglecting. You can't treat a covalent bond *as if* it were purely ionic—which is what you're implicitly doing, by only talking about electrostatic attractions. By that logic, any bond between two of the same element must cost zero energy to break, since there is no electronegativity difference and hence no ionic component.

Coming back to the issue of acidity: one way of looking at it is that if you have a purely ionic bond and want to break it, then all you need to do is to break the electrostatic attraction. On the other hand, if you have a covalent bond (or something in the middle) and want to break that, then you need to do two steps:

1. Convert the covalent bond into a purely ionic bond by shifting electron density from the middle of the bond to the part that will become the anion.
2. Break the ionic bond (i.e. electrostatic attraction).

For a purely ionic bond you only need to do step (2), which is less energy overall, hence easier to lose the proton, hence stronger acid.

You might complain that I've assumed that step 1 *must* cost energy. Is it possible that step 1 could actually be energetically favourable? Well, almost by definition, *no*. If it were more stable to form an ionic bond than a covalent bond, then that's what the atoms would do: they would form an ionic bond. Since they form a covalent bond, we must accept that *that* is a more stable state; and thus it would cost us energy to convert that into an ionic bond.

This analysis might seem simplistic, and it kind of is. But actually, it is not that far off from a sensible thermodynamic cycle, albeit in reverse order: first we break the $\ce{H-X}$ bond homolytically (bond dissociation energy), and then we shift an electron from $\ce{H}$ to $\ce{X}$, i.e. go from $\ce{H + X}$ to $\ce{H+ + X-}$ (ionisation energy + electron affinity).